# Scaling multiple views in android

Tags: java, android, layout, view, scaling

I'm creating a board game in android. In my absolute layout, I have a board view, and a tile view. Those two views can overlap each other, since you're placing a tile onto the board by click and drag. I am not using a bitmap drawing for this since I want to handle two separate onTouchEvent for the board and for the tile.

Problem: I want my board view to be able to zoom in and pan. At the same time, I want to tile to know to scale itself. Is there anyway to do this on android? My current solution is to scale the two view separately(which is a lot of work) but I think there should be a better solution than this out there. Or my approach on this is completely off?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What was your end solution? I have the same issue: a ViewGroup with a View that represents a floor diagram, and sibling Views that represent markers on the plan. All floor and marker graphics are drawn to Canvas using Path objects. The only way I know to zoom a View is to apply a scale transform to the Canvas in onDraw(). It seems that it'll be necessary to invalidate all of the Views in the group, and have them all scale themselves using common zoom and pan variables. This is kind of "okay", but like you I am wondering if there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: ...furthermore, I'm wondering if the Observer / Observable approach could be the way to go here: all child views are Observers of a single object that contains the zoom and pan variables. I got this idea from here: http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/